# Importing XML Data into Database

Tags: mysql, xml, database, perl, xml-parsing

Being the sports nerd that I am, I'm looking to take daily XML files that are produced by the Major League Baseball Website, and import them into either an Access or MySQL database. The issue I'm running into, is that almost every XML file they produce is just slightly different than the last. For example, one game file may have a field named `batter23` that is next to `event22` while the other file calls it `batter24`and is next to `pitcher25`. I know that XML files can be inconsistent, but I know there has to be a way to consistently get the data into a database. Is there anyway to standardize these XML files? Some code that will parse each file in a list, and organize them into a specific style and giving them consistent field names? Currently I import the XML file into a Excel sheet first, where I change the file type to a CSV, but from there the field names and column locations are still different from file to file.

My goal is to have all the files in a structure where I can quickly import them into a database each day, without having to manually change column locations, or field names. I'm open to any and all options, but my experience in most languages are rookie level at best, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Sample of your XML would be necessary to give a good answer.  Otherwise this is an opinion based answer, which is potentially offtopic for StackOverflow. I would suggest looking at `perl` and `XML::Twig` as good options for XML parsing. (And if you can give an XML sample and desired output, I can knock you up an example).

Answer (score 2):

The files are pretty standard as far as XML goes.., you just have to figure what each file represents.

I did a quick look around a Red Sox v Royals game from September 14. (Go Sox!)
In year_2014/month_09/day_14/gid_2014_09_14_bosmlb_kcamlb_1/players.xml
I can see that Ortiz has an id of 120074.

If I look in batters for his player Id, I can see his stats for that game.
(year_2014/month_09/day_14/gid_2014_09_14_bosmlb_kcamlb_1/batters/120074.xml)

It goes on. Basically, in order to load these files into a database, you will have perform some level of processing for them to make any sense.
The IDs don't appear to change between games, but I only took a cursory glance.

As for loading the data, XML::Simple in perl can take an XML and spit out a perl data structure very easily. Unless you need something more heavy duty, this should cover you.

Loading the players.xml:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $players_xml = XMLin('players.xml');

print Dumper $xml;
```

Gives you something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'venue' => 'Kauffman Stadium',
    'date' => 'September 14, 2014',
    'team' => {
        'Boston Red Sox' => {
            'id' => 'BOS',
            'player' => {
                '605141' => {
                    'avg' => '.283',
                    'team_abbrev' => 'BOS',
                    'parent_team_id' => '111',
                    'hr' => '4',
                    'team_id' => '111',
                    'status' => 'A',
                    'last' => 'Betts',
                    'rl' => 'R',
                    'parent_team_abbrev' => 'BOS',
                    'first' => 'Mookie',
                    'rbi' => '12',
                    'game_position' => '2B',
                    'num' => '50',
                    'position' => '2B',
                    'current_position' => '2B',
                    'boxname' => 'Betts',
                    'bats' => 'R',
                    'bat_order' => '1'
                },
                ...
```

It's then trivial to navigate these hashes and insert DB rows as you like.

Comment: The player XML files, and the files that are viewable online all seem to be pretty standard formatting, I didn't see many changes from file to file. The issue arises in the Inning by Inning files, which for some reason don't seem to be viewable online(but were somehow downloadable via a perl parsing script). I can add 2 files for comparison, but they were fairly big and ugly. Will the perl script you provided help with the inconsistent field names? ex: file one lists batter column as `batter` and file 2 lists it as `batter22`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe some URLs to the files you are looking at, and the field names you are seeing would help. I just took a look at the innings for the same game, and the attributes are totally consistent (batter, pitcher, etc).

Comment: After reading your last comment, I went back to check the raw data files, and you are right, the files themselves are consistent. I did not realize this at first, because I was importing them into Excel for easier viewing. Apparently, Excel was renaming the header rows. unfortunately, I have been unable to get the above code to work, so I'm still stuck. I keep getting an error message of "directory of file doesn't exist" or "Permission Denied". This is my first attempt at perl, so i may just be doing it wrong.

Comment: Did you download the XML? You'll have to pass in the correct filename, or use <insert your favourite HTTP package> to download it.. You can also pass in an XML string.